# What does style=?android:attr/... mean?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anybody explain me the tag you see in the headline?

I know that the `?` is to reference to an attribute of the android theme.
What does it mean?

If Google changes the attribute, will it affect my style in my app?

Comment: I found like following links : 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10869421/1318946

http://stackoverflow.com/q/11383033/1318946

Comment: Thank you ;) So i will use custom styles.. ;)