# ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` requires API level 11 (current min is 10)

Tags: android, android-xml, android-cardview

If I use this on my card view as `foreground`, application will crash on pre *API 10*.

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
 //android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">
```

I'm working on a project about seven months and my app worked on every API level until now.. this is forcing me to raise my min SDK.

Can you please help me with this, how can I bypass it.

---

## **temporary answer**

I'm using this

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

insteat of:

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

It's some kind of gray color onClick instead of blue, but I do not care much about the color, So this will solve the crashing problem for now

Comment: Change the min api level to 11 in build.gradle file.

Comment: Do you really support api 10?

Comment: Its clearly says that **requires API level 11 (current min is 10)**. You can change your minimum version or find alternate solution for it

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi  API 10 is important to me

Comment: @azizbekian  yes

Comment: @DastakWall Kudos to you, man.

Comment: @DastakWall you can set it programmatically, but it will have the same problem. I am not sure but there may be some third party libraries to do that.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi at least if I programmatically use this on above API 10, app will not break on pre 10 , thanks for the reply

Comment: if you find the ans then add answer to your qustion

Comment: @JJG  of course ...

Comment: Have a look at [Usage of ?android:attr/ in backwards compatible apps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11383185/6340019). Hope it will help you

Comment: `?selectableItemBackground` is what you should be using when you have AppCompat. It's support counterpart to `?android:selectableItemBackground`. Basically if there's an attribute *without* the `android:` prefix you should be using that. ***///*** This approach will fail below Lollipop. Foreground corners will NOT be rounded and foreground will be drawn over card shadow.

Answer (score 0):

User
`android:foreground="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` instead of `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Using `?attr:` (or the `?` shorthand) instead of `?android:attr` references the support library, so is available back to API 7.